# Animating MathJax through SVG animations

Tags: javascript, css, animation, svg, mathjax

I know MathJax symbols are SVG diagrams, and as SVG diagrams can be animated as easily as this:

```css
svg {
  width: 150px;
}

svg:hover path {
  d: path("M8,2 L2,8 L2,8 L2,8 L2,8 L2,8");
}

svg path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  transition: 2s;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 10 10">
  <path d="M2,2 L8,8 L2,8 L2,2 L8,2 L8,8" />
</svg>

<p>Hover to see the animation.</p>
```

I thought of animating MathJax through SVG. Just one problem: as in the above SVG, the diagram on hover should be just a two command diagram (`"M8,2 L2,8"`). And it essentially is, the last 4 commands are redundant ... until you realize that the number of commands in the original SVG path and the hover path should be equal, otherwise ...

```css
svg {
  width: 150px;
}

svg:hover path {
  d: path("M8,2 L2,8");
}

svg path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  transition: 2s;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 10 10">
  <path d="M2,2 L8,8 L2,8 L2,2 L8,2 L8,8" />
</svg>

<p>No animation on hover!</p>
```

the animation won't work.

After tweaking MathJax-to-SVG code from [this](https://viereck.ch/latex-to-svg/) website, these are the paths of x letter and = symbol in MathJax.

```css
svg {
  width: 150px;
  border: 2px dotted gray;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 -442 900 453">
    <path transform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 0 0)" 
          d="M52 289Q59 331 106 386T222 442Q257 442 286 424T329 379Q371 442 430 442Q467 442 494 420T522 361Q522 332 508 314T481 292T458 288Q439 288 427 299T415 328Q415 374 465 391Q454 404 425 404Q412 404 406 402Q368 386 350 336Q290 115 290 78Q290 50 306 38T341 26Q378 26 414 59T463 140Q466 150 469 151T485 153H489Q504 153 504 145Q504 144 502 134Q486 77 440 33T333 -11Q263 -11 227 52Q186 -10 133 -10H127Q78 -10 57 16T35 71Q35 103 54 123T99 143Q142 143 142 101Q142 81 130 66T107 46T94 41L91 40Q91 39 97 36T113 29T132 26Q168 26 194 71Q203 87 217 139T245 247T261 313Q266 340 266 352Q266 380 251 392T217 404Q177 404 142 372T93 290Q91 281 88 280T72 278H58Q52 284 52 289" />
</svg>

<svg viewBox="0 -442 900 453">
    <path transform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 0 0)" 
          d="M56 347Q56 360 70 367H707Q722 359 722 347Q722 336 708 328L390 327H72Q56 332 56 347ZM56 153Q56 168 72 173H708Q722 163 722 153Q722 140 707 133H70Q56 140 56 153" />
</svg>
```

I wrote a script (originally in Python, but just for an on-site solution ...) in JavaScript that will make the number of commands in x and = paths equal (simply by adding the last command again and again).

```js
let xPath = "M52 289Q59 331 106 386T222 442Q257 442 286 424T329 379Q371 442 430 442Q467 442 494 420T522 361Q522 332 508 314T481 292T458 288Q439 288 427 299T415 328Q415 374 465 391Q454 404 425 404Q412 404 406 402Q368 386 350 336Q290 115 290 78Q290 50 306 38T341 26Q378 26 414 59T463 140Q466 150 469 151T485 153H489Q504 153 504 145Q504 144 502 134Q486 77 440 33T333 -11Q263 -11 227 52Q186 -10 133 -10H127Q78 -10 57 16T35 71Q35 103 54 123T99 143Q142 143 142 101Q142 81 130 66T107 46T94 41L91 40Q91 39 97 36T113 29T132 26Q168 26 194 71Q203 87 217 139T245 247T261 313Q266 340 266 352Q266 380 251 392T217 404Q177 404 142 372T93 290Q91 281 88 280T72 278H58Q52 284 52 289"
let equalsPath = "M56 347Q56 360 70 367H707Q722 359 722 347Q722 336 708 328L390 327H72Q56 332 56 347ZM56 153Q56 168 72 173H708Q722 163 722 153Q722 140 707 133H70Q56 140 56 153"

function lettersInString(string) {
  alpha_counter = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    if (string[i].match(/[a-zA-Z]/i)) {
      alpha_counter += 1;
    }
  }
  return alpha_counter;
}

let newEqualsPath = equalsPath + "Q56 140 56 153".repeat(lettersInString(xPath) - lettersInString(equalsPath))

document.getElementById('path').innerHTML = newEqualsPath;
```

```html
<p>New Equals Path: <code id="path"></code></p>
```

But on trying it out:

```css
svg {
  width: 150px;
}

svg path {
  transition: 2s;
}

svg:hover path {
  d: path("M56 347Q56 360 70 367H707Q722 359 722 347Q722 336 708 328L390 327H72Q56 332 56 347ZM56 153Q56 168 72 173H708Q722 163 722 153Q722 140 707 133H70Q56 140 56 153Q56 140 56 153Q56 140 56 153Q56 140 56 153Q56 140 56 153Q56 140 56 153Q56 140 56 153Q56 140 56 153Q56 140 56 153Q56 140 56 153Q56 140 56 153Q56 140 56 153Q56 140 56 153Q56 140 56 153Q56 140 56 153Q56 140 56 153Q56 140 56 153Q56 140 56 153Q56 140 56 153Q56 140 56 153Q56 140 56 153Q56 140 56 153Q56 140 56 153Q56 140 56 153Q56 140 56 153Q56 140 56 153Q56 140 56 153Q56 140 56 153Q56 140 56 153Q56 140 56 153Q56 140 56 153Q56 140 56 153Q56 140 56 153Q56 140 56 153Q56 140 56 153Q56 140 56 153Q56 140 56 153Q56 140 56 153Q56 140 56 153Q56 140 56 153Q56 140 56 153Q56 140 56 153");
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 -442 900 453">
    <path transform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 0 0)" 
          d="M52 289Q59 331 106 386T222 442Q257 442 286 424T329 379Q371 442 430 442Q467 442 494 420T522 361Q522 332 508 314T481 292T458 288Q439 288 427 299T415 328Q415 374 465 391Q454 404 425 404Q412 404 406 402Q368 386 350 336Q290 115 290 78Q290 50 306 38T341 26Q378 26 414 59T463 140Q466 150 469 151T485 153H489Q504 153 504 145Q504 144 502 134Q486 77 440 33T333 -11Q263 -11 227 52Q186 -10 133 -10H127Q78 -10 57 16T35 71Q35 103 54 123T99 143Q142 143 142 101Q142 81 130 66T107 46T94 41L91 40Q91 39 97 36T113 29T132 26Q168 26 194 71Q203 87 217 139T245 247T261 313Q266 340 266 352Q266 380 251 392T217 404Q177 404 142 372T93 290Q91 281 88 280T72 278H58Q52 284 52 289" />
</svg>
```

doesn't seem to work. Why is this happening? Is there some problem with the script, or with `transform` attribute, or something else? If yes, then how to fix it? If no, then how do I animate the x symbol to turn into an = sign? Or at least, at alternate solution to animate MathJax from SVG? Thanks!

Comment: One starts MQHQ... and the other MQTQ... all the commands must be the same.

Comment: @RobertLongson Ooh ... do you know of some other way of animating SVGs of this sort then?

Comment: No, you have to make them the same.

Comment: @RobertLongson Can you please reference some material where I can know more about it? (conditions on animating SVG paths, etc)

Comment: https://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/IG/resources/svgprimer.html#multi-valued_animation or https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html